# Is there a function already existing in mxgraph library to color an image contour?

Tags: mxgraph

I'm trying to color a contour image with mxgraph. But for this, I dont't know if it exists an already mxgraph function that allows to color a contour image. Is there in the mxgraph library this kind of function or not?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a function for this specific task, but you can try to use the functions that colors the cells and then translate that to your image.

You can also check the [documentantion](https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/docs/js-api/files/index-txt.html) for more info about the mxGraph functionalities